# Failed to translate JSON in request error in Watson discovery query call

Tags: python-3.x, watson-discovery

Using the `ibm-watson` Python SDK version 5.3.0 with the following code example:

```
from ibm_watson import DiscoveryV2, ApiException
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator
import json


url = 'https://api.eu-de.discovery.watson.cloud.ibm.com'
version = '2020-08-30'

apikey = '...'
project = '...'
collection = '...'

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(apikey)
discovery = DiscoveryV2(version=version, authenticator=authenticator)
discovery.set_service_url(url)

try:
    result = discovery.query(
        project_id=project,
        collection_ids=collection,
        query='text:searchterm',
        table_results=True
    ).get_result()


    print(json.dumps(result, indent=2))

except ApiException as ex:
    print(f'Failed. Status code {ex.code}: {ex.message}')
```

Returns the following error from the server.

> Failed. Status code 400: Failed to translate JSON in request: Cannot
> deserialize value of type
> `scala.collection.immutable.List<java.lang.String>` from String value
> (token `JsonToken.VALUE_STRING`)

The error only occurs if `collections_ids` or `table_results` is specified.

Answer (score 0):

The server is telling you that the JSON sent to it doesn't match what it expects to process.

The `collections_ids` and `table_results` are incorrectly formatted for the API request.

As per the [API documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/discovery-data?code=python#query).

- `collections_ids` must be a list. So change to `collections_ids=[collections]`
- `table_results` expects an object. To correct use `table_results={ 'enabled': True }`